# having problem with my currency converter application

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i was trying to make a currency converter application. It asks the amount from the user, and asks if the amount entered is in PKR (pakistan rupee) or USD (us dollar) and gives an option whether to convert to indian rupee, chinese yuan or euro. It then converts the amount into the chosen currency. the problem im having is that when i choose to convert pkr to some other currency, it also converts usd, and same if i choose to convert usd, it also converts pkr. im sorry if the code is difficult to read, im a beginner in python.

```
print ("""Welcome to currency converter!
You can use this application to convert USD and PKR to other major currencies.
You can currently convert to Indian Rupees, China's Yuan, and Euro. More currencies will be hopefully added in the future!

""")

user_amount = input ("Enter the amount that you would like to convert: ")
user_usd_pkr = str(input ("Is the amount entered by you in PKR or USD? Use the letter 'P' for PKR and the letter 'U' for USD:  "))


# This section covers the conversion of PKR to other currencies.

if user_usd_pkr == "P" or user_usd_pkr == "p":
    user_convert_choice = input("""Would you like to convert to -
    
    1. Indian Rupees. (use letter I)
    2. China's Yuan.  (use letter C)
    3. Euro.          (use letter E)
    
    """)
    if user_convert_choice == "I" or user_convert_choice == "i":
     indian_rupees = int(user_amount) * 0.48171
     print (f"{user_amount} PKR is {indian_rupees} Rs.")
    elif user_convert_choice == "C" or user_convert_choice =="c":
        china_yuan = int(user_amount) * 0.042300
        print (f"{user_amount} PKR is {china_yuan} Yuan.")
    elif user_convert_choice == "E" or user_convert_choice =="e":
        euro = int(user_amount) * 0.0054100
        print (f"{user_amount} PKR is {euro} Euro.")
    else:
        print ("You have not entered a valid choice. The program will restart and enter a valid choice this time.")

# This section covers the conversion of USD to other currencies.


elif user_usd_pkr == "U" or user_usd_pkr == "u":
    user_convert_choice = input("""Would you like to convert to - 
    
    1. Indian Rupees. (use letter I)
    2. China's Yuan.   (use letter C)
    3. Euro.          (use letter E)
    
    """)

if user_convert_choice == "I" or user_convert_choice == "i":
    indian_rupees = int(user_amount) * 73.27
    print (f"{user_amount} USD is {indian_rupees} Rs.")
elif user_convert_choice == "C" or user_convert_choice == "c":
    china_yuan = int(user_amount) * 6.44
    print (f"{user_amount} USD is {china_yuan} Yuan.")
elif user_convert_choice == "E" or user_convert_choice == "e":
    euro = int(user_amount) * 0.82
    print (f"{user_amount} USD is {euro} Euro.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the indentation.
The lowest if-elif-elif block is not inside the `elif user_usd_pkr == "U"` block.

Here is a corrected version:

```py
print("""Welcome to currency converter!
You can use this application to convert USD and PKR to other major currencies.
You can currently convert to Indian Rupees, China's Yuan, and Euro. More currencies will be hopefully added in the future!

""")

user_amount = input("Enter the amount that you would like to convert: ")
user_usd_pkr = str(input(
    "Is the amount entered by you in PKR or USD? Use the letter 'P' for PKR and the letter 'U' for USD:  "))


# This section covers the conversion of PKR to other currencies.

if user_usd_pkr.upper() == "P":
    user_convert_choice = input("""Would you like to convert to -

    1. Indian Rupees. (use letter I)
    2. China's Yuan.  (use letter C)
    3. Euro.          (use letter E)

    """)
    if user_convert_choice == "I" or user_convert_choice == "i":
        indian_rupees = int(user_amount) * 0.48171
        print(f"{user_amount} PKR is {indian_rupees} Rs.")
    elif user_convert_choice == "C" or user_convert_choice == "c":
        china_yuan = int(user_amount) * 0.042300
        print(f"{user_amount} PKR is {china_yuan} Yuan.")
    elif user_convert_choice == "E" or user_convert_choice == "e":
        euro = int(user_amount) * 0.0054100
        print(f"{user_amount} PKR is {euro} Euro.")
    else:
        print("You have not entered a valid choice. The program will restart and enter a valid choice this time.")

# This section covers the conversion of USD to other currencies.


elif user_usd_pkr.upper() == "U":
    user_convert_choice = input("""Would you like to convert to -

    1. Indian Rupees. (use letter I)
    2. China's Yuan.   (use letter C)
    3. Euro.          (use letter E)

    """)

# indentation was missing here:
    if user_convert_choice == "I" or user_convert_choice == "i":
        indian_rupees = int(user_amount) * 73.27
        print(f"{user_amount} USD is {indian_rupees} Rs.")
    elif user_convert_choice == "C" or user_convert_choice == "c":
        china_yuan = int(user_amount) * 6.44
        print(f"{user_amount} USD is {china_yuan} Yuan.")
    elif user_convert_choice == "E" or user_convert_choice == "e":
        euro = int(user_amount) * 0.82
        print(f"{user_amount} USD is {euro} Euro.")
```

BTW you can use `user_usd_pkr.upper() == "U"` so you don't have to check for `"U"` and `"u"`.